Is it true that any closed convex balanced absorbing set in a dual pair is always weakly compact?
Based on my understanding of several theorems of TVS and duality, I seem to have derived a contradictory result. Therefore, I would like to ask where my understanding might be wrong. Below is my derivation.

Let $X, Y$ be two vector spaces and $\left<\cdot,\cdot\right>: X\times Y \to\mathbb R$ a bi-linear mapping, who makes $X$ and $Y$ separate each other , then we say $\left<X,Y\right>$ is a dual pair (see wiki). The weak topology of $X$ is the weakest topology that makes every $\left<\cdot, y\right>$ continuous, and similarly the weak topology of $Y$ is the weakest topology that makes every $\left<x,\cdot\right>$ continuous.
From the weak representation theorem (e.g. Theorem 3.10 of papa rudin, or this wiki page), the (topological) dual space of $X$ is $\left<\cdot, Y\right>$, and similarly the dual space of $Y$ is $\left<X,\cdot\right>$. Since $\left<\cdot, Y\right>$ with its weak-* topology is equivalent to $Y$ with weak topology (they are both the weakest topology that makes every $\left<x,\cdot\right>$ contiunuous), the canonical mapping from $Y$ to $\left<\cdot, Y\right>$ is a linear homeomorphism. Thus the (weak) bi-dual of $X$ is itself, i.e. $X^{**} = X$.
Let $A$ be a weakly closed convex balanced absorbing set in $X$. The polar set $A^\circ \subseteq Y$ is defined as $$A^\circ = \left\{y \in Y \left| \sup_{x \in A}|\left<x,y\right>| \leq 1 \right.\right\}.$$
Bi-polar theorem says that $A^{\circ\circ}$, which is a set in $X$, equals to the closure of the convex balanced hull of $A$. Since $A$ is itself closed convex balanced, we have $A^{\circ\circ} = A$.
Banach-Alaoglu theorem says that the polar set of a set $A$ in $X$ is always a compact set in the weak-* topology of its dual space, and in the context of dual pairs it is $Y$. Similarly, the dual of $A^\circ$, which is $A^{\circ\circ}$, should be weakly compact in $X$.
The above reasoning seems to derive a conclusion that every weakly closed convex balanced absorbing set must be weakly compact. However, this sounds contrast the Kakutani theorem of the reflexive Banach spaces, which says that for a Banach space, it is relfexive if and only if the closed unit ball is weakly compact. In a Banach space the closed unit ball is a weakly closed convex balanced absorbing set, yet it can not always be compact since otherwise every Banach space is reflexive according to the Kakutani theorem, which is obviously not true. My question is where in the above reasoning is wrong.

P.S. notice that $X^{**} = X$ does not implicity make $X$ a reflexive space, because here for dual spaces we defaultly endow them with the weak-* topology, while in reflexive space we talk about dual spaces with strong topology.

Banach-Alaoglu says the polar of a neighborhood of the origin is weak-$^\ast$ compact, not the polar of an arbitrary subset. In this case, you wish to apply Banach-Alaoglu to $A^\circ \subset Y$ where $A$ is the closed unit ball of $X$ and $Y = X^\ast$, in which case $A^\circ$ is the closed unit ball of $X^\ast$, which is not a neighborhood of the origin (unless $X$ is finite-dimensional) as the relevant topology on $Y = X^\ast$ is the weak-$^\ast$ topology.

Of course, if you consider the norm topology on $Y$, then the unit ball is a neighborhood of the origin, but then the polar of the unit ball lies within $Y^\ast = X^{\ast\ast}$ (where now both $\ast$ indicates the norm dual), and is in fact the closed unit ball of $Y^\ast$, which is indeed weak-$^\ast$ compact. For this to mean anything for the closed unit ball of $X$, you would then need $X = X^{\ast\ast}$ canonically, i.e., $X$ is reflexive.

@DavidGao Tes you are right. This seems be the point I was missing: the closed unit ball of an infinite dimensional Banach space is not a neighbor of origin, and thus Banach-Alaoglu might not apply.

@DavidGao However, I have an additional question: why Banach-Alaoglu has to require a neighborhood of the origin? If you check Rudin's proof (Theorem 3.15), although in the theorem the set $V$ is assumed to be a neighborhood of origin, the proof doesn't actually uses this condition. The only thing used in the proof is that $V$ is absorbing (meaning that for any point $x$, there is a scalar $\lambda$ such that $x \in \lambda V$). However, the closed unit ball, despite not being a neighborhood of the origin, seems indeed to be an absorbing set, which should make the Banach-Alaoglu applicable...?
